# Tizen emulator incompatible with WLS2

Tags: tizen, haxm, hypervisor, tizen-emulator

I found out that the settings required to run tizen emulator on win10 are incompatible with WSL2. Specifically the `hypervisorlaunchtype` must be set to off for it to work, which prevents WSL2 from launching. I created two scripts to turn it on and off if needed, they are in the answer, but the only thing they do is elevate themselves and run `bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype (auto/off)`. If anyone managed to get the two to play nice together please do show us how. Hope this will help someone in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Script to turn hypervisor off (tizen emulator works):

```
If (-NOT ([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal] [Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole]::Administrator))
{
  # Relaunch as an elevated process:
  Start-Process powershell.exe "-File",('"{0}"' -f $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path) -Verb RunAs
  exit
}
# Now running elevated so launch the script:
& bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off
```

Script to turn hypervisor on (WSL2 works):

```
If (-NOT ([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal] [Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole]::Administrator))
{
  # Relaunch as an elevated process:
  Start-Process powershell.exe "-File",('"{0}"' -f $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path) -Verb RunAs
  exit
}
# Now running elevated so launch the script:
& bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype auto
```

Comment: It works - I had found the same solution (using bcdedit turning hyperv on and off) after reading this other article https://www.petri.com/how-to-disable-hyper-v-completely-in-windows-10 - 

but it's a horrible hack having to switch this every time and reboot. 
Moreover, I use WSL all the times for things like using GIT... which I use for the Tizen project.

I really hope Samsung fixes this.

Comment: @DanieleMuscetta I would not count on that, Samsung itself is switching to Android for their watches and there is not much need for tizen as a lightweight alternative to android either, because chips have gotten more powerful. Tizen is on its last legs I would say.

Comment: Interesting... they were trying to move away from Android for their phones, trying to rely on vertical integration not having to pay royalties to Google... but I don't think that took off, yet, either... there aren't many devs nor apps. The story will unfold itself in a few years time, I guess. I have this Tizen app for Samsung Smart TV's  and for the foreseable future it will still have to be maintained...  they have recently re-done their 'seller' office website (which as an app vendor you use to publish packages to their store)... so I think for TV's it will stick around for some time...

Comment: @DanieleMuscetta Yeah, TV's are gonna be the last to fall, maybe together with fridges and such, but on mobile devices I believe Tizen is done for

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for this post. I discovered this as well and [posted a bug on MS WSL](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/9288)

I was hoping they would have a more elegant solution than manually changing the hypervisor setting, but the response was: "Conflicting hypervisors can't be running at the same time" :(